# Android file content change when power lost

Tags: android, file, kotlin

I am trying to write to file on android. But I realized that the file content will automatically rollback to a previous version of it even if it is save.
I use Android 10, on a device that name x96 mate Android box.

First time write to file
[image]

then next time write to file
[image]

After I unplug and plug back in
[image]

I have tested on another device running Android 7.1.2 and the file still have latest content.
Can anyone help me with this?? Thank you.

Updated: Code I have used

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val data = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Date())
                writeFile(path, data)
            }

@Throws(IOException::class)
suspend fun writeFile(filePath: String, content: String) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
        val bw = BufferedWriter(FileWriter(filePath))
        bw.write(content)
        bw.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you think anyone can help you if you only provide screenshots as your question.

Comment: Does it work correctly on a mobile device since I don't think there is anything wrong with your program.

Comment: @RahulRawat It worked perfectly on my Galaxy s7 running Android 8. I think something's wrong with the Android Q device.

Comment: It shouldn't be or else there would have been an uproar from the dev community.